# upgrading to mamp 3 corrupted databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I had MAMP 2 and just upgraded to mamp 3 because I upgraded to yosemite. I followed this tutorial on how to upgrade: http://joejoomla.com/sound-off/157-how-to-upgrade-mamp.html

Seems pretty easy. Call your old MAMP "MAMP_OLD" and drag the htdocs and db folders over and youre done. Well when I open PHPMyAdmin, the databases are there and when I click on them I see the tables. But when I click on a table it says this table doesn't exist. I tried to open a couple more databases and they do the same thing.

How do I repair or fix these databases to work with the updated MySQL thats with MAMP 3?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I needed to grab the ib_logfiles from MAMP_OLD/db/mysql/ib_logfiles and put it in my MAMP/db/mysql folder. Guess it stores the db data in these ib_logfiles.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a cookie! 

I resetted a single database-folder via Time Machine in MAMPs mysql-Folder. After that i got lots of errors for that database on every operation (drop, truncate, etc..).

Simply by deleting all 'ib_'-files inside MAMP/db/mysql/ the problem was solved. MAMP created new 'ib_'-files after restarting the MAMP-Server and now the problems are gone! Thanks!